# Get only the subnet mask number on linux using bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sh, subnet

I have tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33150670/10946386) :

`ip -o -f inet addr show | awk '/scope global/ {print $4}'`

but that outputs IP address with the subnet mask number:

`192.168.1.108/24`

I only want the number `24`

Comment: `ip -o -f inet addr show | awk '/scope global/ {split($4, s, "/"); print s[2]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should only output the two or single digit subnet mask number like `24` :

`ip -o -f inet addr show | grep -Po "/\K[[:digit:]]{1,2}(?=.*scope\sglobal)"`

if you want it to output with the slash `/24` :

`ip -o -f inet addr show | grep -Po "/[[:digit:]]{1,2}(?=.*scope\sglobal)"`

Answer (score 6):

`ip addr show` can output JSON data, so it makes it reliably explicit to parse with `jq`:

```sh
ip \
  -family inet \
  -json \
  addr show |
    jq -r '.[].addr_info[0] | select(.scope == "global") | .prefixlen'
```

`man ip`:

> `-j`, `-json`
>
> Output results in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON).

Comment: Never learned of this program-friendly (plumbing) interface of `iproute2`! TIL!

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `awk`, you may use `gensub`:

```sh
txt='scope global'
ip -o -f inet addr show | \
 awk -v search="$txt" '$0 ~ search{print gensub(/.*\//, "", 1, $4)}'
```

Here,

- `-v search="$txt"` - passes the value of `txt` to `awk` as `search` variable
- `$0 ~ search` - checks if there is a match in the whole line
- `gensub(/.*\//, "", 1, $4)` - removes all up to an including the last slash in the fourth field (replaces with an empty string (`""`), search is performed once only (`1`)).

Answer (score 0):

I used regex on your command to select everything after `/`

```sh
ip -o -f inet addr show | awk '/scope global/ {print $4}' | grep -o '[^/]*$'
```

Comment: grep after awk is useless, since awk can do what grep does.

Comment: so all can be formatted to only AWK or GREP?

Comment: See my comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752278/get-only-the-subnet-mask-number-on-linux-using-bash/65753258#comment116254960_65752278)