# How do I get the network mask in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking

I am trying to get the network mask using bash in that way:

```
192.168.1.0/x
```

I tried with:

```
ip -o -f inet addr show | awk '/scope global/ {print $4}'
```

but the output is:

```
192.168.1.123/x
```

So this way doesn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Given the IP and netmask, how can I calculate the network address using bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429420/given-the-ip-and-netmask-how-can-i-calculate-the-network-address-using-bash)

Comment: Network or mask or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are masking the last 8 bits, 192.168.1.123/24 is the same as 192.168.1.0/24. If you want the last byte to be 0 for cosmetic reasons, I would use `sub()` in awk:

```
ip -o -f inet addr show | awk '/scope global/{sub(/[^.]+\//,"0/",$4);print $4}'
```

Comment: I lost all hope in bash and have written c helper

Comment: That's a good idea. :) I started to implement it in awk, but bitwise operations can produce surprising results in awk. (Especially since awk has no way to get a 4byte unsigned integer). Following the gawk manual: `In short, using gawk for any but the simplest kind of bitwise operations is probably a bad idea; caveat emptor`.. Btw, I can also recommend Python's `ipaddr` and `netaddr` libraries. They are very convenient to use.